# Varargs-Constructor cannot act as default constructor using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, javafx, variadic-functions, default-constructor

**FXML-View:**

```
....
    <GridPane...>
        <PersonController... />
    </GridPane...>
....
```

**Class PersonController:**

```
public PersonController(Person... personsToExclude) {
    FXMLLoader.load("PersonControllerView.fxml")
    this.personsToExclude = personsToExclude;
}
```

This code sample leads to an excpetion, because the class cannot be invoked without a default constructor (by the FXMLLoader). Now my question: You CAN use this constructor as default constructor. You can create such an object like this:

```
PersonConstructor pc = new PersonConstructor(); // This calls the upper constructor
```

Why isn't reflection able to use this constructor too? Varargs appear to be arrays internally which will be null by default if no parameter was handed over.

Was this design decision solely made to reduce complexity (it actually does reduce it a little bit for the reader) or are there any other reasons why it is important to still have a "real" default constructor?

Comment: It's not really a default constructor, though.  That code is equivalent to `PersonConstructor pc = new PersonConstructor(new Person[] {});`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - This seems to be a pure Java question, i.e. "why can't I use a vararg ctor as a default ctor via reflection?".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: So you're reading the above as "Why doesn't `Class#newInstance()` work when the class doesn't have a zero-args constructor but does have a constructor accepting a single varargs argument?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Something like that, yes.

Comment: Sorry for my english, but @OliverCharlesworth is right. I wanted to ask what he understood. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Oliver Charlesworth is correct, your question is really:

> Why doesn't `Class#newInstance()` work when the class doesn't have a zero-args constructor but does have a constructor accepting a single varargs argument?

If so, I don't think we can properly answer it unless there's a quote from the design process around adding varargs to Java.

We can speculate. My speculation is: ***Simplicity***

1. `newInstance()` is older than varargs. Until varargs were added to the language, there was no ambiguity: It could only call the nullary (zero-arguments) constructor. So they may have felt that extending it to handle constructors accepting one varargs argument was code bloat and/or scope creep for the method. After all, if you really want to do that, you can look up the relevant constructor and call that instead.
2. Alternately, they may have felt that `newInstance`'s documentation ruled out calling such a constructor. Let's look at the [JavaDoc for `newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

   > Creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object. The class is instantiated as if by a new expression with an empty argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.
   >
   > Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception...

   The first paragraph supports the idea that it could call a constructor with just one varargs argument. The second paragraph, though, mentions a "nullary" constructor specifically (though in passing). A "nullary" constructor is a zero-argument constructor, specifically, not just a constructor that *can* be called with no arguments.
3. Doing so would markedly complicate `newInstance()`, because rather than just looking for a constructor that accepts no arguments, it would need to look through all the constructors for one that accepts a single argument where [`isVarArgs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#isVarArgs--) is true.
4. Changing `newInstance()` to do what you're suggesting adds a new error mode: It's perfectly possible for your `PersonConstructor` class to have *more than one* constructor that can be called via `new PersonConstructor()`:

   ```
   public class PersonConstructor
   {
       public PersonConstructor(String... args) {
       }

       public PersonConstructor(Person... args) {
       }
   }
   ```

   So which one should `newInstance` call? It can't decide, so it would have to throw, throwing a new error it hadn't thrown prior to the addition of varargs to the language.

All in all, if I were on the team making the decision, I would also have had `newInstance()` only consider true nullary constructors and not constructors accepting a single varargs argument. (I would also have updated the JavaDoc to say that. :-) )

Comment: Wow, I didn't thought about your last point. Thx :) You made some good points here!

Answer (score 1):

Variable argument lists are implemented entirely in the compiler. Methods that take arrays and methods that take vararg arrays are compatible with each other - for example, you can use vararg signature

```
void foo(String... args)
```

to override a non-vararg signature

```
void foo(String[] args)
```

and vice versa ([demo](http://ideone.com/BcO9Yw)).

> Was this design decision solely made to reduce complexity?

It is hard to guess why this particular design decision has been made, but at least part of the reason can be attributed to designer's reluctance to make changes to libraries and JVM. Java 5 update, in which variable argument feature has been introduced, opted for full backward compatibility on the bytecode level, despite the fact that it was a very big update, which introduced generics.

If you would like to work around this limitation, implement a no-argument constructor that routs the call to the constructor which takes an array:

```
public PersonController(Person... personsToExclude) {
}
public PersonController() {
    this(new Person[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Varargs appear to be arrays internally which will be null by default if no parameter was handed over.

This is not true. If you call a vararg method (or constructor) without any argument, the method (or constructor) is still a method with one array argument. And not null will be passed, but an empty array, as Oliver already has pointed out.

So the answer is: A vararg constructor has definitely one argument, and so it cannot be a default constructor.

Comment: Ah right. But even of it has a parameter, you still can call it without anything?

Comment: That's what I am saying above. You must distinguish between the formal method signature (which is: it has one array argument), and the actual call (which can be: empty, one Person, two Person etc.).